# How to store private key in android keystore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keystore

I want to store private key in android KeyStore, but I have problem with KeyStore.getInstance("JKS") is error like this:
java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found.

Please help me why it's not know for this instance?

- I have file load my keystore: mykeystore.jks

My code as below:

```
try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
        X509Certificate certificate = generateCertificate(keyPair);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        char[] password = "xxxxxx".toCharArray();
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path\\mykeystore.jks")) {
            ks.load(fis, password);
        }
        Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];
        certChain[0] = certificate;
        ks.setKeyEntry("key1", keyPair.getPrivate(), password, certChain);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

- Result error: 
  java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found

Comment: Please update your question and include the code & error message as text, not as image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67779409/6314955 check this

Answer (score 4):

A Java KeyStore (JKS) is **not available** on Android.

The recommended keystore on android is `AndroidKeyStore`. For your case, get keystore instance using `AndroidKeyStore` instead of `JKS` and set password as `null` because `AndroidKeyStore` does not accepts any password:

```java
//...
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
//...
ks.setKeyEntry("key1", keyPair.getPrivate(), null, certChain);
```

In an `AndroidKeyStore`, you cannot set password for keys or keystore because keystore file(s) managed by Android system itself. Also, generating keys inside to the `AndroidKeyStore` instead of importing (eg. calling `setKeyEntry`) is more secure and recommended way.*(In supported devices, Android generates keys in separated secure hardware. Which means, nobody, including app itself cannot export keys from that device)*

So, generate keys using `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder` instead of `KeyPairGenerator`.

You can check documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

But if you think `AndroidKeyStore` is still not suitable for you, you can list available keystore types in Android via:

```
// Iterate in security providers
for(Provider provider: Security.getProviders()) {
  for(Object item: provider.keySet()) {
    if(item.toString().startsWith("KeyStore.")) { // grep KeyStores
      Log.d(TAG, "Keystore: " + item.toString() + " available in provider: " + provider.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

In an Android Emulator `Pixel 2 API 28` this code outputs:

```
Keystore: KeyStore.BouncyCastle available in provider: BC
Keystore: KeyStore.PKCS12 available in provider: BC
Keystore: KeyStore.BKS available in provider: BC
Keystore: KeyStore.AndroidCAStore available in provider: HarmonyJSSE
Keystore: KeyStore.AndroidKeyStore available in provider: AndroidKeyStore
```

Which means, available KeyStore's are:

```
BouncyCastle
PKCS12
BKS
AndroidCAStore
AndroidKeyStore
```